# Service cannot be started. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly "assemblyname.dll"

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services, setup-project

NOTE: I have done exhaustive research on this question, there are many supposed solutions out there, none of which have actually worked for me.

After successfully installing a windows service onto a clients computer, I notice that it doesn't start automatically as it is supposed to. When I try to start it manually, I get the error above. I took a look at the Events Viewer log, and here is the error logged there: "Service cannot be started. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly "assemblyname.dll" or one of it's dependencies. The specified module could not be found"

It turns out that my .dll, even though I can see it in the installation folder (I did the side-by-side), the system is not able to connect to it. Someone suggested making sure the application file name and the config file name match, mine already did, and my service is set to run on the Local System Account. NOTE: Everything works fine on the dev box, and the client machine has the requisite 4.5 .NET framework for the service to run.

QUESTION: How can I correct this? How can I make sure the system on the client machine is able to see the .dll file that the service uses?

Any help is appreciated here. Let me know if further clarification is needed.

Thanks

Comment: Are the executable binaries in the same folder as the dll?  I'm assuming yes, but I want to verify.

Comment: @DavidW the service was developed on a 64 bit system, but compiled for 32 bit

Comment: @CDC everything is in the same folder.

Comment: In a case like this, ProcMon is your friend. Fire it up, start the service, and ProcMon should tell you exactly which assembly is MIA.

Comment: The log from the Event Viewer already specified the .dll that is missing, my question is how to make sure the client system can see the .dll. It is in the installation folder, but the system says it's missing.

Comment: Downloading Procmon now..

Comment: @DivineCoder Try to compile your .NET solutions with `Any CPU` profile. There's no 32 or 64bit compilation. It's just a limitation to avoid executing .NET code on top of unwanted CPU architectures.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I'll try your suggestion in a few minutes

Comment: @DivineCoder I've doubts about this, but who knows if your service is looking in the wrong folder because of something related to x86 or x64...  And, after all, I understand you don't need to compile to 32 or 64bit since the produced intermediate language (IL) is the same (that's the advantage of JIT compilers: they compile IL into machine code so your code is CPU-agnostic)

Comment: Two things I would suggest: 1) update your Path variable to point to the directory with the dll, or 2) put the dll in the \windows\system32 directory.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions guys, I have tried all of them with no success. Pocmon showed that the user account logged onto the system did not have enough permissions to access the .dll : fixed that, but issue still persists

Comment: I double checked the installation variables in my project, the [TARGETDIR] variable is pointing to the correct location with the .dll, I also put the .dll in \windows\system32 per @SteveFerg suggestion: issue is still there..

Comment: You could also try putting it in the \windows\SysWOW64 directory.

Comment: As I think about it, maybe the error is not exactly the problem you "think" you are experiencing. Have you tried using a different log on account for the service? Also are there any other files referenced in the dll that could be causing the dll to fail?

Comment: I compiled the project as AnyCPU, set the target platform to x86 for the setup project, installed the project on a 64 bit machine and everything worked perfectly, services run, no issues. The service is installed in the /Program Files (x86) folder on the 64 bit system. When I install it on the 32 bit system, the error comes up. I'm not getting a BadImageFormat exception so I know the platform type is not the issue. I have tried to add the dll as an embedded resource, then manually find it in the code, but this does not seem to resolve the issue either.... stumped for days..... literally

Answer (score 1):

**Possible solution**

> Try compiling it in x86, could be a 64-bit dll, make sure you have the 32-bit version.

Comment: Thanks for the post @NickProzee, I did double check what bit architecture the .dll is, corflags tells me it is actually set to AnyCPU, so this should not be an issue. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Try putting The dll in The same folder as the .exe

Comment: The usual way to debug these is the Fusion Log Viewer. It will tell you what it tried to load and where it looked. If the Dll is literally in the same folder as the service exe then the Dll doesn't match the client requirements in AssemblyVersion, strong name etc. It is unlikely to be architecture because the load would fail with BadImageFormatException, not "can't find file".  Note that you also may have missed an assembly that "assemblyname.dll" is dependent on.

Comment: @PhilDW thanks for your response, could you guide me on how to check that the client AssemblyVersion requirement match the DLL I am using? So far I did use corflags to check the bit architecture of the DLL, and it is set to AnyCPU. The client system is a 32bit machine. What other checks can I do? Your answer seems to be closer to what my issue is.

Comment: You're .NET, so your exe has a reference in the build to a Dll. A build binds that exe to that exact version of the Dll. This pretty basic stuff - .NET doesn't only care about the name - the assemblyversion must match, and language etc. For example If you have a * in your assemblyversions then your versions are unpredictable, and if you build in the wrong order (client before Dll) and you are guaranteed a mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

OK guys I finally solved my problem. I ran dependency walker and It gave me a list of dlls that were missing, but it turned out they had nothing to do with the dll I was using. But I decided to install Windows SDK for Win 7 with the redistributables, and this solved the problem i was having. There you have it folks, hope this helps someone else going forward. Cheers!

Comment: You will your clients to install the Windiows SDK?

Comment: @PhilDW I'm gonna build that into my installer as a requirement, I'm adding logic to look for it, if it's not there I'll present them with a splash screen that has the download link, much like checking for the correct .Net framework.